# Server Error in /Reports Application

Tags: asp.net

I am using crystal report 13 for my asp.net project-framework 4.0. When I am running application locally the report runs perfactly. But accessing through the internet, it is giving below error:

```
Server Error in /Reports Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Reports/ReportViewer.aspx
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927 ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

But I am using framework 4. But in above error it is showing .net framework2. 
All other forms are working except reports.
Is there any changes have to make in IIS? 
I am using the version IIS7.5
Browsing through IIS is also giving this error.
Can anyone tell me how to resolve?

```
<httpHandlers><add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></httpHandlers></system.web>



<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <handlers>
          <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx"
               type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      </handlers>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Share your web.config, both local and on server. Many dlls work by adding handlers in web.config. Settings are different for IIS6 and IIS7

Comment: How to share the folder.Please explain

Comment: Copy the relevant part related to httphandlers and paste it in your question

Comment: @user1547589 What is your app pool on server, probably you select .net framework 2.0.50727.4927 as your pool

Comment: @vikas,my application pool is .netframework4 itself